# VSCode 上で PostgresSQLの「CREATE TABLE」に表示される波線の意味は？

Tags: vscode, postgresql

VSCode上にて、以下の様なPostgresSQLのクエリを送りました。

```
create table Goods
(ID          char(4)      Not Null, 
 goods_name  char(100)    Not Null,
 goods_class varchar(32) Not Null,
 price       integer,
 unit_price  integer,
 regist_day  date,
 primary key (ID)) ;
```

この時、以下の様に赤波線が「char(4)」の下で確認されました。
[image: 実際の画面]

赤い波線が出る場合はエラー箇所だと考えているのですが、このクエリはエラーが出ずに実行されます。
その為、何故上記の様な赤い波線が出るのか理由が分からずに困惑しています。
ご返信いただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

<追記>
・VSCode上で実行しています。
・インストールした拡張機能 = PostgresSQL(作成者 : Chris Kolkman)

<追記2>
保存することで、赤い波線が消えるようになりました。
しかし、何故保存しないと赤線が出てしまうのかが疑問です。
この疑問への回答をして頂けると非常に助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Visual Studio Code 上での表示であれば、「波線にポインターを置くことでポップアップが出る」「Problem欄(WinではCtrl-Shift-M)に出力がされている」のいずれかで何かしらの情報が記載されていませんか？

Comment: それが、「char近辺でのエラー」という文言しか表示されないです、、、。

Comment: 手元の VS Code で試してみたのですが、問題を再現できませんでした。手順はコマンドパレットから "PostgreSQL: New Query" を選択したあと質問文のクエリをコピー＆ペーストしました。環境は以下の通りです。PostgreSQL 拡張 (ckolkman.vscode-postgres) 1.4.3, VS Code 1.81.0, PostgreSQL server 14.8, macOS Ventura 13.5, MacBook Pro Apple M2 Max

Comment: 自分はWindows上で行っていますが、機種によってエラーの有無が変わるのでしょうかね、、、
そんなことないとは思うのですが、、、。